# Array of Arrays grouped by Key to be displayed as a table Python

Tags: python

pretty new to python so apologies if I'm going about this wrong! I am building a website on Flask that gets information from the fantasy premier league api for me and my friends, and displays the resulting scores by week in a table. I have retrieved the scores and manipulated them such that I have the following array:

```
[
[{'GameWeek': 1, 'JH Score': 71}, {'GameWeek': 1, 'Harry Score': 70}, {'GameWeek': 1, 'Alex Score': 64}], 
[{'GameWeek': 2, 'JH Score': 80}, {'GameWeek': 2, 'Harry Score': 41}, {'GameWeek': 2, 'Alex Score': 52}],
[{'GameWeek': 3, 'JH Score': 40}, {'GameWeek': 3, 'Harry Score': 60}, {'GameWeek': 3, 'Alex Score': 46}], 
[{'GameWeek': 4, 'JH Score': 41}, {'GameWeek': 4, 'Harry Score': 29}, {'GameWeek': 4, 'Alex Score': 65}], 
[{'GameWeek': 5, 'JH Score': 65}, {'GameWeek': 5, 'Harry Score': 56}, {'GameWeek': 5, 'Alex Score': 65}], 
[{'GameWeek': 6, 'JH Score': 63}, {'GameWeek': 6, 'Harry Score': 54}, {'GameWeek': 6, 'Alex Score': 38}], 
[{'GameWeek': 7, 'JH Score': 47}, {'GameWeek': 7, 'Harry Score': 65}, {'GameWeek': 7, 'Alex Score': 46}], 
[{'GameWeek': 8, 'JH Score': 87}, {'GameWeek': 8, 'Harry Score': 70}, {'GameWeek': 8, 'Alex Score': 88}]
]
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Group those key/value pairs by gameweek, i.e.

```
{'GameWeek': 1, 'JH Score': 71, 'Harry Score': 70, 'Alex Score': 64},
{'GameWeek': 2, 'JH Score': 80, 'Harry Score': 41, 'Alex Score': 52},
```

etc

2. Display this information in a table in browser, of the structure

```
 GameWeek    JH Score   Harry Score   Alex Score
   1            71           70            64
   2            80           41            52
```

etc

Thank you in advance for your help. Apologies if I have not been clear enough!

Comment: for the 2nd part of the question, are you using any frontend technologies? or are you just going to return some html so that the browser will show the content?

Comment: This are two questions, the second part depending on what you use in the front-end

Comment: hi Samridh, I think just html for now, haven't incorporated any front end technologies yet

Comment: Ask a separate question for the second question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this code below if you re using Python 3.5+:

```
res = []

for gmwks in arr:
    wk = {}
    for dic in gmwks:
        wk = {**wk, **dic}
    res.append(wk)
```

This will combine all dicts as you wanted.

doc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/10929089

Comment: Of course, in Python 3.5+ they added a dict functionallity that means those 2 dictionaries will merge into one; as far as you could know, dictionaries are uniqued valued, so if you see the code, variable wk will get the wk content itself plus the actual dict.